# super.onCreate(savedInstanceState); does not call immediately the parent class's onCreate() method.Why?

Tags: android, inheritance, android-activity

I extend all my activities from BaseClass. Thus i want to initialize common variables in onCreate() of BaseActivity class. However, super.onCreate(savedInstanceState); does not call immediately the parent class's onCreate() method. Why?

```
public class SplashActivity extends BaseActivity {
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);     // after this line executed, next line executed rather than the onCreate() of parent BaseActivity
        ...
    }
}

public class BaseActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState, @Nullable PersistableBundle persistentState) {
        ...
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes It will call Super `onCreate` first. Try to debug it to verify . Now once you get it Explain the problem you are facing ..

Comment: Why do you say it didn't call it? What are you seeing/experiencing?

Comment: i debugged and write logs. BaseActivity's onCreate() never called. I tried to add baseActivity to manifest but that does not solved it too.

Comment: You dont need to add base activity in your Manifest Just create java class extend it from Activity or AppCompactActivit

Comment: I use same Approach in my most of Applications.. As you saying base class oncreat never call its not possible.. Some time IED makes Issue So restart you Android Studio and may be u can see debugger in super class

Comment: ok i solved the problem i called wrong onCreate() method. That was the problem. more than one implementation of oncreate exists.